# outputText won't show anything / cannot access class?

Tags: java, jsf, javabeans

So I'm new with this JSF stuff and thought I write some code just to see how it works. Actually I did things [like here in this tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uls1B1UIXvE). But I'm not even able to do the simplest thing.

To keep things clear I just made one class:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class Bean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public final String TEXT = "Bean";
}
```

my index.xhtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<title>JEE</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Output1: <h:outputText value="#{Bean.TEXT}"/></h3>
    <h4>Output2: #{Bean.TEXT}</h4>
</body>
</html>
```

If I start this on Eclipse I dont get any output for `Bean.TEXT` , like if I would not have any access to this class:

[image]

So there should be some text after Output1 and Output2. I don't see any exceptions regarding the Bean class. How do I debug stuff like this? Any suggestions?

PS:

Here my web.xml (I made it somehow like in the tutorial):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>JavaEE</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Servlet Class</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Servlet Class</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Servlet Class</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Servlet Class</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Console output:

```
Dec 24, 2013 3:36:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
Dec 24, 2013 3:36:18 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:JavaEE' did not find a matching property.
Dec 24, 2013 3:36:18 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Dec 24, 2013 3:36:18 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Dec 24, 2013 3:36:18 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 573 ms
Dec 24, 2013 3:36:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Dec 24, 2013 3:36:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
Dec 24, 2013 3:36:20 PM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
INFO: Initializing Mojarra 2.2.4 ( 20131003-1354 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.4@12574) for context '/JavaEE'
Dec 24, 2013 3:36:20 PM com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderFactory createInstance
INFO: JSF1048: PostConstruct/PreDestroy annotations present.  ManagedBeans methods marked with these annotations will have said annotations processed.
Dec 24, 2013 3:36:21 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Dec 24, 2013 3:36:21 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Dec 24, 2013 3:36:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 2284 ms
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within EL context you access beans via names that were previously declared by means of annotations or configuration file. If you don't specify `name` element of `@ManagedBean` annotation then it'll become the simple class name with the first letter decapitalized (if two initial letters are not uppercase). In your case the bean can be accessed as `#{bean}` while you tried to access it as `#{Bean}` which is wrong (but could have worked if you declared it as `@ManagedBean(name="Bean")`).

Also, it's worth noting that it is a common practice to have only one mapping for the faces servlet and that is `*.xhtml`, so you'd be better off if you removed the three specified servlet mappings from your web.xml and left only one.

Comment: Thx for the information. Now I tried #{bean.TEXT} instead of Bean.TEXT -> but still the same result. I also tried to write @ManagedBean(name="Bean") but eclipse is giving me an error "The attribute name is undefinied for the annotation type ManagedBean."

Comment: Edit: Now I got the problem, I was using "import javax.annotation.ManagedBean;" instead of "import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;". Now I'm able to use (name="BeanName") and also my output is working.